# Dropbear ssh tunneling segfault on Android

Tags: android, ssh, init, dropbear, dbclient

I'm an android developer and we are trying to make a ssh tunneling between Android device and Linux Host. I'm using dropbear for this solution.

Here is my steps:

1) I'm connecting to my host via dbclient with 0 port

```
dbclient -i "$RSA_KEY" -f -N -R 0:localhost:22 "$HOST" -y &> /sdcard/out
```

2) Then I'm running dropbear

```
dropbear -E -R
```

3) And now I'm able to connect to device via ssh from my host using public key and port in /sdcard/out

```
ssh -i ssh_rsa_key root@localhost -p 50216
```

Here is it, and it's works perfectly.
For my solution I need to make tunneling automatically.

I have created bash script under /system/bin/ (build android image with script in it). Added corresponding service in init.rc to run my script automatically.

```
 service myScript /system/bin/myScript
      class core
      user root
      group root
      disabled
```

The script actually runs by system every 5 sec. but when I'm trying to connect to device I receive following error message:

```
Aiee, segfault! You should probably report this as a bug to the developer
```

The strangest thing is that when I'm running my script manually it works fine but when system runs the **same** script I receive upper described error message.

"dmesg", "logcat", even "ssh ... -vvv" don't give any error message.

I think problem is in "dropbear" itself, because when system runs "dbclient" and then I run "dropbear -E -R" manually , tunneling works correctly.

This is my output of "ssh ... -v"

```
  OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to localhost port 50643.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file ssh_rsa_key_to_box type -1
  debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
  debug1: identity file ssh_rsa_key_to_box-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2017.75
  debug1: no match: dropbear_2017.75
  debug1: Authenticating to localhost:50643 as 'root'
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:M1PmvueMNfm4q47UlzVWZMdB6YzxyYBy4I5hden9ctU
  debug1: Host '[localhost]:50643' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /Users/haykbeglaryan/.ssh/known_hosts:23
  debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: ssh_rsa_key_to_box
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:50643).
  debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
  debug1: Entering interactive session.
  debug1: pledge: network
  debug1: Sending environment.
  debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
  debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
  Aiee, segfault! You should probably report this as a bug to the developer
  debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
  debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  Connection to localhost closed.
  Transferred: sent 2640, received 1816 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
  Bytes per second: sent 312354.4, received 214861.9
  debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in environment variable “LD_LIBRARY_PATH” which dropbear uses. When I print it

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/vendor/lib:/system/lib
```

But when init.rc tries to read it, it's null. I Just harcdoced this line in dropbear sources and now it's works correctly.